# How to configure email properties in JBoss JBPM / WildFly?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, classpath, jbpm

I'm trying to configure the SMTP mail settings in JBPM Business Central + KIE Server (apps that run inside a WildFly server)

The documentations says that I should configure a JNDI resource OR place a file `email.properties` in the root of the classpath (info taken from here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.4/html/user_guide/email_task)

I would prefer the second option, but I can't figure out where I should place that `email.properties` file. Looking around for a solution, I got into some complicated doc about creating a module with XML files and I don't know what.

**Is there no easy way to place a file in the root of the WildFly classpath?**

thanks!

Comment: Try to add properties directly in the <system-properties> tag of standalone.xml. 
I haven't used JBPM, but have faced a similar problem with wildly and spring with context to application.properties file. Please let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a file in a classpath you could add the mail configuration by jboss-cli:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=jbpm-mail-smtp/:add(host=smtp.gmail.com, port=465)

/subsystem=mail/mail-session=jbpm/:add(jndi-name=java:/jbpmMailSession, from=username@gmail.com)

/subsystem=mail/mail-session=jbpm/server=smtp/:add(outbound-socket-binding-ref=jbpm-mail-smtp, ssl=true, username=username@gmail.com, password=password)
```